# Preferred word for 'T-shirt'

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

Which word is more commonly used to refer to 't-shirt', *remera* or *camiseta*?

Comment: As the vocabulary for things like clothing and food vary greatly by region, it would be helpful if you could tell us which region's vocabulary interests you (if you know).

Comment: The way I learnt it was "camiseta". That's how people say it in Spain!! Additionally, "camisa" means "shirt".

Answer (score 7):

Clothing (and meal) is quite region specific. In Argentina "remera" is widely preferred ("camiseta" is used only for underwear, or for sporting clothes that identify a team).

[Here](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camiseta) is a list by country.

Comment: When I was going to buy a "camiseta" in Argentina, turned out the word means *pyjamas* there. What I wanted was indeed a "remera".

Comment: But +1 especially for including the link, showing there are many more words for T-shirt than just "camiseta" and "remera".

Answer (score 6):

In **Spain**, you should definitely use `camiseta`, other options are very uncommon...

Comment: Also, `polo` for [polo shirt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polo_shirt)

Comment: In Argentina, "polo shirt" is "chomba" :-)

Answer (score 2):

In Mexico (at least the regions where I have been), the preferred word for a T-shirt is *playera*.

Answer (score 0):

In **Chile** we wear `polera`. (*Camiseta* is underwear and *remera* is not used).

I have noticed that in the dubbing of some films says `franela`.